# Is there a way to put attributes in innerHTML? or switch divs based on a dropdown without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a chrome extension/app creator and I have a drop down menu that lets you choose if the thing for chrome it makes will be a extension or app. based on that, it makes the inner html change. The only problem is that the innerHTML doesn't want to accept attributes, probably because of the quotations. I could make the drop down onchange clear the rest of the contend and create lots of elements and scripts, but is the scripts part possible? I guess I could make it show/hide the divs, but is there a way to do that with ***simple***/no jQuery? I just wand it to look like [this start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jLEt.png) and [end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6nuC.png) image.  This is the not working code I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Google extension/app maker</h1>
  <form>
    Type:
    <select id="type" onchange="selectType()">
      <option value="1">Extension</option>
      <option value="2">App</option>
    </select>
    <p id="inputs"></p>
  </form>
  <script>
    function selectType() {
      var typevalue = document.getElementById("type").value;
      if (typevalue == 1) {
        document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML = "Extension name: <input id=" + name + "> Version: <input id=" + version + "> ";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML = "bye";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong before you downvote!

Comment: Try escaping the quotes, or use single quotes for the attributes. both should work

Comment: Use single quotes inside a double quoted string

Comment: You're right about the quotes in the html string.  Just change it to `"Extension name: <input id=\"name\"> Version: <input id=\"version\"> "` (and ignore the down-voters.  They're not stopping you getting an answer :)

Comment: That worked perfectly, @ThomasScheffer !

Comment: And i bet the others work too!

Comment: btw @Archer my last account got locked out of asking questions because of downvoters, so it did stop me

Comment: Learn to use your developer tools! The error should have pointed you right to that line.

Comment: @EthanZoneCoding You got an answer.  They didn't stop you :)  If you've been locked out before you should really pay attention to this link -> **[ask]**

Comment: I know there is a way to unlock it, @Archer , but I will make sure this nice new account stays good.

Comment: Voting to close as the error was simply typographical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes of the attribute value.

```
document.getElementById("inputs").innerHTML = "Extension name: <input id=\"name\"> Version: <input id=\"version\"> ";
```

Comment: I did that and used single quotes instead. I will upvote that answer when it lets me!